# Can VMs on Google Compute detect when they've been migrated?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, avx, avx512

Is it possible to notify an application running on a Google Compute VM when the VM migrates to different hardware?

I'm a developer for an application (HMMER) that makes heavy use of vector instructions (SSE/AVX/AVX-512).  The version I'm working on probes its hardware at startup to determine which vector instructions are available and picks the best set.

We've been looking at running our program on Google Compute and other cloud engines, and one concern is that, if a VM migrates from one physical machine to another while running our program, the new machine might support different instructions, causing our program to either crash or execute more slowly than it could.

Is there a way to notify applications running on a Google Compute VM when the VM migrates?  The only relevant information I've found is that you can set a VM to perform a shutdown/reboot sequence when it migrates, which would kill any currently-executing programs but would at least let the user know that they needed to restart the program.

Comment: There actually is a way to get notified when live migration takes place using Metadata server. This info is available directly on the VM. I've added the info to my answer. You can also check out: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#maintenanceevents

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly the sort of information I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ensure that your VM instances never live migrate between physical machines in a way that would cause your programs to crash the way you describe.

However, for your use case you probably want to specify a minimum CPU platform version. You can use this to ensure that e.g. your instance has the new Skylake AVX instructions available. See the documentation on [Specifying the Minimum CPU Platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform) for further details.

Comment: Just to double-check, does that mean that, if I were to set a minimum CPU platform of Haswell or better, but actually get issued a Skylake EP machine,  the VM would never be live-migrated to a Haswell machine?  That's the sort of case I'm worried about -- our software will start up, detect that it's on Skylake, and use AVX-512, which will then crash if it's moved to Haswell.

Comment: If you set a minimum CPU platform and use CPUID to do feature detection you won't encounter any crashes. I don't work on Compute Engine, but I've asked the appropriate team to update the documentation about the Minimum CPU Platform feature to provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Live Migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) docs:

> **Live migration does not change any attributes or properties of the VM**
>   **itself**. The live migration process just transfers a running VM from
>   one host machine to another. All VM properties and attributes remain
>   unchanged, including things like internal and external IP addresses,
>   instance metadata, block storage data and volumes, OS and application
>   state, network settings, network connections, and so on.

Google does provide few controls to set the [instance availability policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options) which also lets you control aspects of live migration. Here they also mention what you can look for to determine when live migration has taken place.

> [**Live migrate**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#live_migrate)
>
> By default, standard instances are set to live migrate, where Google
>   Compute Engine automatically migrates your instance away from an
>   infrastructure maintenance event, and your instance remains running
>   during the migration. Your instance might experience a short period of
>   decreased performance, although generally most instances should not
>   notice any difference. This is ideal for instances that require
>   constant uptime, and can tolerate a short period of decreased
>   performance.
>
> When Google Compute Engine migrates your instance, it reports a system
>   event that is published to the list of zone operations. You can review
>   this event by performing a gcloud compute operations list --zones ZONE
>   request or by viewing the list of operations in the Google Cloud
>   Platform Console, or through an API request. The event will appear
>   with the following text:
>
> ```
> compute.instances.migrateOnHostMaintenance
> ```

In addition, you can detect directly on the VM when a maintenance event is about to happen.

> [**Getting Live Migration Notices**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#maintenanceevents)
>
> The metadata server provides information about an instance's
>   [scheduling options and settings](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options), through the scheduling/
>   directory and the maintenance-event attribute. You can use these
>   attributes to learn about a virtual machine instance's scheduling
>   options, and use this metadata to notify you when a maintenance event
>   is about to happen through the `maintenance-event` attribute. By
>   default, all virtual machine instances are set to live migrate so the
>   metadata server will receive maintenance event notices before a VM
>   instance is live migrated. If you opted to have your VM instance
>   terminated during maintenance, then Compute Engine will automatically
>   terminate and optionally restart your VM instance if the
>   automaticRestart attribute is set. To learn more about maintenance
>   events and instance behavior during the events, read about [scheduling
>   options and settings](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options).
>
> You can learn when a maintenance event will happen by querying the
>   `maintenance-event` attribute periodically. The value of this
>   attribute will change 60 seconds before a maintenance event starts,
>   giving your application code a way to trigger any tasks you want to
>   perform prior to a maintenance event, such as backing up data or
>   updating logs. Compute Engine also offers a [sample Python script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#maintenanceevents)
>   to demonstrate how to check for maintenance event notices.
>
> You can use the maintenance-event attribute with the waiting for
>   updates feature to notify your scripts and applications when a
>   maintenance event is about to start and end. This lets you automate
>   any actions that you might want to run before or after the event. The
>   following Python sample provides an example of how you might implement
>   these two features together.

You can also choose to terminate and optionally restart your instance.

> [**Terminate and (optionally) restart**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#terminate_and_optionally_restart)
>
> If you do not want your instance to live migrate, you can choose to
>   terminate and optionally restart your instance. With this option,
>   Google Compute Engine will signal your instance to shut down, wait for
>   a short period of time for your instance to shut down cleanly,
>   terminate the instance, and restart it away from the maintenance
>   event. This option is ideal for instances that demand constant,
>   maximum performance, and your overall application is built to handle
>   instance failures or reboots.

Look at the [Setting availability policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#settingoptions) section for more details on how to configure this.

If you use an instance with a GPU or a preemptible instance be aware that live migration is not supported:

> [**Live migration and GPUs**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration#gpusmaintenance)
>
> Instances with GPUs attached cannot be live migrated. They must be set
>   to terminate and optionally restart. Compute Engine offers a 60 minute
>   notice before a VM instance with a GPU attached is terminated. To
>   learn more about these maintenance event notices, read Getting live
>   migration notices.
>
> To learn more about handling host maintenance with GPUs, read
>   [Handling host maintenance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#host-maintenance) on the GPUs documentation.
>
> [**Live migration for preemptible instances**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration#preemptiblemaintenance)
>
> You cannot configure a [preemptible instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) to live migrate. The
>   maintenance behavior for preemptible instances is always set to
>   `TERMINATE` by default, and you cannot change this option. It is also
>   not possible to set the [automatic restart](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration#autorestart) option for preemptible
>   instances.

As Ramesh mentioned, you can specify the minimum CPU platform to ensure you are only migrated to an instance which has at least the minimum CPU platform you specified. [At a high level it looks like](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform#choosing_a_minimum_cpu_platform):

> In summary, when you specify a minimum CPU platform:
>
> - Compute Engine always uses the minimum CPU platform where available.
> - If the minimum CPU platform is not available or the minimum CPU platform is older than the zone default, and a newer CPU platform is
>     available for the same price, Compute Engine uses the newer platform.
> - If the minimum CPU platform is not available in the specified zone and there are no newer platforms available without extra cost, the
>     server returns a 400 error indicating that the CPU is unavailable.

Comment: TL:DR: live migration can't add or remove CPUID feature flags from an already-running VM, but stopping and restarting the VM could result in it starting on a machine with more or fewer features than previously.  So you only need to detect insn set extensions at least once per reboot.  (And thus once per process startup is fine unless you use a checkpoint/restore system to restore a process's state after a reboot).